# How to set redis cluster master and slave?

Tags: redis-cluster

I create a redis cluster use "redis-trib create" commond, I have a few questions about redis-cluster:

1. can redis-trib explicitly set which host is master and which host is slave? or any other way to do so;
2. how to set cluster auth password;
3. when set maxmemory , how the cluster works? does one master up to the maxmemory limit then store data to another master?

Answer (score 5):

1. You are supposed to assign the roles one by one; or write a script by yourself, to properly send [`cluster addslots`](http://redis.io/commands/cluster-addslots), [`cluster meet`](http://redis.io/commands/cluster-meet) and [`cluster replicate`](http://redis.io/commands/cluster-replicate) commands to the right Redis
2. Not suggested to do so in the cluster environment, and here are some [words](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/redis-db/Z8lMxTfDct8/Rny9BIK9xGYJ) from antirez himself
3. It affects only the one you send `config set maxmemory` to. It's possible that different nodes in a cluster have different maxmemory, and serve different numbers of slots

===

More details about #1:

First choose your master instances, use `redis-trib.rb create` without `--replicas`. Now you have a cluster that contains only masters.

Connect to each of your desired slaves with `redis-cli`, and send these commands

```
> cluster meet MASTER_IP MASTER_PORT
# wait several seconds, and use cluster nodes to ensure that it has joined the cluster

> cluster replicate MASTER_NODE_ID
# wait, and use cluster nodes to ensure it has become a slave
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I can't understand the item 1, can you give me more details?

Comment: @aodavid Added links to the commands and how to work with them. Hope this would help.

Comment: Thanks very much, i got it.

Comment: I would also add, that you do `CLUSTER REPLICATE` before you do `CLUSTER ADDSLOTS`